# Saving Quickblox video chat in phone memory

Tags: ios, iphone, video, avfoundation, quickblox

Hi I am using Quickblox in my iPhone app for Video chat. Now I want to save the chat sessions into phone memory (camera roll). Is it possible. I want to save it with sound.

I searche dfor this and I found [this](http://quickblox.com/developers/Chat/Video_chat_recording) and [this](http://quickblox.com/developers/Chat/Video_chat_recording) code from quickblox
I am not able to record the video from these. Please help me to do this. If possible please explain with code.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to use custom capture session

http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-videochat-ios#Use_custom_capture_session

With this you have 2 callback - one for video raw data and the second one is for audio raw data

Next - use Apple AQRecorder sample files to merge both streams into single file and save to the camera roll 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SpeakHere/Listings/Classes_AQRecorder_h.html